# Is it possible for a Windows installation to not have the C drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I'm developing an application and I want to justify why I changed the location of some files from `c:\` to `%temp%`.

I think the best reason would be that not all Windows computers have the `C:` drive.

Is that true?

Comment: If your asking if a system can boot off a different drive letter the question is of course it can.  Its just typically done.  You should be able to justify using %temp% for the simple fact, it will always be correct, because its a system varible and hard coding the path is a horrible idea.

Comment: @Ramhound I know that it's possible to boot to D:. I want to know if it's possible to not have C: at all.

Comment: Of course.  You would be fighting default behavior but its entirely possible to change the boot drive to `D` then all other drives to something other then `C`

Comment: Yes, it is quite possible. You can even get to a windows installation with **only** drive F:\ by accident. Been there, got the T-shirt. Cursed a lot of programs which did not work due to bad coding.

Comment: I think the important thing is that applications should use whatever is specified in the tmp or temp environment variable and allow the user to decide what is there. The existence or absence of the C drive seems irrelevant.

Comment: Yikes, not only is this a development question, I'd also hold that `TEMP` can be overridden by the user, while well-known location when retrieved via API are the single source of truth from which `TEMP` would be populated (unless overridden).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's true! Windows' location could be on any drive letter. Even because you can have more than one OS installed on the same computer.

You also could have a computer without a `C:` drive letter.

You can read about other [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Comment: The files are temporary, and I want to know if it's possible for that drive to not exist, not if windows would be installed to it or not.

Comment: @JaderDias Okay! So no problem to install in temp folder. Answer edited! The Answer still the same you can't fix in C: driver folder.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its true!

C Drive its not essential for a computer. You can have one just with D: drive for example.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether there can be a Windows installation without a `C:`, there definitely can be a Windows installation with a `C:` where you can't write, for example because there's no directory on that drive where your application has write permission, or because that drive is full.

If you need to create temporary files, create them in the directory indicated by the `TEMP` environment variable (i.e. `%TEMP%`).

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you can have another name for the Windows home drive. However, you can use `%HOMEDRIVE%` or `%PROGRAMDATA%` to find out where to put your files.

Windows has many other [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: But if Windows home drive is D:, it happens only when we have a C: drive? Can we make a Windows installation without C:?

Comment: @JaderDias Yes you can make a installation without C!

Comment: @JaderDias the idea is to rely on the environment variables instead of a hard path.